# Does not display user reputation properly when the question is more than 1 sentence long

Tags: support, question-lists, internet-explorer

Found this bug on stackoverflow this morning. It does not display the user reputation for user LoneXcoder for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045973/saving-values-of-an-array-plus-values-of-other-variables-holds-reference-to-it-i) question when I searched for all C# questions. I also got a browser error, which I've attached here. I'm using IE8. Here's a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The style issue comes up only for this user and question on the question list page on stack overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by user credits? Can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Sorry I meant the user reputation. And I am not able to take a screen shot. I did try it and for some reason it takes a black screenshot. I'll try again and see if I can post it in a bit.

Comment: Added a screenshot and I found some more questions with the same issue. Its happening when the length of the question is more than 1 sentence long.

Comment: Do you have any user styles or anything overriding styles on the site or in general? I don't have IE8 but I can't reproduce on IE9.

Comment: [This](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/ie-error/) may be of interest.

Comment: I'm just using IE8 with default settings

Comment: Sorry, that's IE8 with compat view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off Compatibility View (the torn page icon in the address bar next to the refresh icon), and this should go away.

Comment: Fixed it, Thanks. Its a bit dodgy that it doesn't work with Compat view.

Comment: Well, Compat View is essentially IE **7** - which is *pretty long in the tooth* now. We really can't test with it, and the number of people using it is... tiny.

Comment: I just checked, you're right. It doesn't work with either IE7 or compat view

Comment: Having said that, even when compat view is turned off, the invalid character error still comes up.

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce that one, but it seems to be in the ad code - can you post a separate report for that, with a full screenshot?

Comment: I'll do that now.

Comment: Here's the new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144268/getting-a-browser-error-on-ie8