# Invalid character in adzerk script on IE8

Tags: bug, status-norepro, advertising, internet-explorer-8

I'm using IE8 (without compat view) and when I search all C# questions on stackoverflow, I see a browser error on the bottom left on the status bar. On double clicking it, I see this error.

[image]

This is the full error when I copy error details:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 00:18:24 UTC


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://engine2.adzerk.net/z/8277/adzerk2_2_17_45?keywords=c%23,x-user-registered,x-1500plus-rep&xReferrer=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045973/saving-values-of-an-array-plus-values-of-other-variables-holds-reference-to-it-i
```

Comment: I tried searching with no C# filter and see the same error

Comment: Just for kicks, try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5, or from the F12 dev tools) and see if it still happens.

Comment: I tried it at home on Firefox, IE9 and chrome and neither of them have this issue. So either it is a specific IE8 bug or it was a question (not on the first page anymore) that had a link with some characters that were making the page not load correctly.

Comment: I tried a hard refresh too. Still see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[James Avery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148831/james-avery) of Adzerk has looked into this issue, but couldn't reproduce it.  We couldn't either on our end, so I'm going to close as no repro.

If you see this happening again, let us know and see if you can get the script source that is causing the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I still see it on IE8, IE7 and IE8 compatibility view. The script source is - var scriptSrc = "http://engine2.adzerk.net/z/8277/adzerk2_2_17_45";

Comment: @Divi - do you have any plugins or extensions installed? Can you hit this url directly and see what it returns?  http://engine2.adzerk.net/z/8277/adzerk2_2_17_45?keywords=c%23,x-user-registered,x-1500plus-rep&xReferrer=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045973/saving-values-of-an-array-plus-values-of-other-variables-holds-reference-to-it-i

Comment: No, don't have any plugins or extensions installed and I see the problem only on stackoverflow and no other stack-exchange subsite. Hitting the url doesn't do anything. Opens a blank page

Comment: Can you hit this page and log the time you did it? That way we can check the logs to see if we can find the issue. http://web12.adzerk.net/z/8277/adzerk2_2_17_45

Comment: @JamesAvery: Just tried it

Comment: Divi - could you send me an email at james at adzerk.com? I don't see anything in the logs for this and want to get to the bottom of it.